# Send an xml file as attachment with android

Tags: android, xml, email

im trying to make my android application send an email with an xml file as attachement. All is working fine except for the fact that the xml file I receive is empty. I checked to make sure the file isn't empty on my phone...

Here is the code I use to send the mail:

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.setType("text/Message");
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"someone@somewhere.com"});
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MySubject");
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file///sdcard/rapport.xml"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Send it out!"));
```

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be your file protocol declaration there. You could either try *Uri.fromFile*, or maybe just use "file:///" (yours appears to be missing the colon, unless that's just a typo here).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)

Also, mine is close to yours, but this is how I have done it in the past (and it seems to work):

```
File f = new File("path_to_file");
   if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" +
         f.getAbsolutePath()));
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "BODY");
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
   } else {
     Toast.makeText(Main.this, getString(R.string.fileNotExistBlah),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: Thnx Charlie, the missing colon wasn't a typo just here :,( 
I promiss to read my code more carefully before posting questions in the future. Non the less you still saved my day!