# File attachment in mail in android

Tags: android

Please help me, I want to attach file in mail, How can do it.
I am sending mail simply but how can to add attachment file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you sending the email? Are you using intents, or talking to smtp directly? What does your code look like?

Comment: use Inent feaute........

Comment: Help us help you. Your question is not specific enough.

Comment: use Inents in our source code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125206/403053

Comment: I am using this feature, file is attach but in mail, file is not attachement in mail of recieving mail....

Comment: Have you verified that the attachment URI is correct and the attachment gets added to the mail message properly?